# Need ideas on Troubleshooting a Navigation Problem

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Basically I have a page in sharePoint 2007. That contains two web parts.

The first webpart is a custom navigation system created with css that is a drop-down menu. The second webpart is an excel spreadsheet.

When you hover over a link in the dropdown menu, the menu extends into the second webpart. Since the menu extends this far once you scroll into the second web part the menu disappears.

Ive got a temporary solution to extend the first webpart by 200px but this solution is not good enough as it adds too much noticeable whitespace.

I really do not know what I can do to fix this. but any ideas would help.

Answer (score 1):

On the DIV containing your navigation, set the Z-INDEX in the CSS to a very high number (like 10000).  See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp for more details on the Z-INDEX CSS property.

Comment: I tried the solution you recommended. i added a z-index: 10000; tag to my code. but the problem still persists.

Comment: Using the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar (F12), use the selector to look at the CSS being applied to the spreadsheet webpart to see what tags are making it appear above your navigation container.